# first tab active by default when page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show the first tab active when the page load for the first time, after that when the user chose which tab to display

when load the page all tab will be closed until click on them to show the content, I need to show the first tab by default

i think it's from javascript code!!

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top:55px;">
  <button class="tablinks " onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">دهان</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">تصليح دواليب</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">اصلاحات ميكانيكية</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent ">
  <h3>دهان</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>تصليح دواليب</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية 22222</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>اصلاحات ميكانيكية</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية   لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية33333</p>
</div>
```

Comment: add class `active` to first tab

Answer (score 0):

Just add `active` class to the first tab and `style="display:block";` in the first tab content `div`.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tab {
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" style="margin-top:55px;">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">دهان</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">تصليح دواليب</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">اصلاحات ميكانيكية</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
  <h3>دهان</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>تصليح دواليب</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية 22222</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>اصلاحات ميكانيكية</h3>
  <p>لصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسيةلصفحة الرئيسية   لصفحة الرئيسية لصفحة الرئيسية33333</p>
</div>
```